# Making vanilla JavaScript ES6 wait for Ajax to finish

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

I'm building a website using 2 APIs.

I'm trying to get my Google Maps init to wait for a response to come back.

My code:

```
let Url = "https://ipinfo.io/json";
async function getInfo(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  // console.log(response);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
let ipInfo = getInfo(Url);
console.log(ipInfo);

//Google maps
function initMap() {
  var place = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: place
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Now how do I make the initMap() wait for getInfo() to finish? I was trying something like

```
let ipInfo = getInfo(Url).then(function(){initMap()...Rest of code});
```

But it didn't wait

Comment: Why wait?...init the map while requests are being made then update locations once they are received

Comment: Well same thing. How can I tell it to send the data AFTER it gets here? If I do it differently it'll just be undefined

Comment: Make requests inside initMap and store reference to map object so you can add markers, set center etc once data received. Also using ipinfo not as accurate as using navigator to get users current position

Comment: Could you give me a code example? I'm kind of lost.

Comment: There are lots of examples all over the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `async` and `await`, you should be able to do:

```
let ipInfo = await getInfo(Url);
// rest of code using ipInfo
```

If you want to use the `Promise` format, then what you had should work:

```
getInfo(Url)
  .then(info => {
    initMap();
    // more code
  });
```

Just know that it won't return the value back to a variable.

If that didn't work, it's very likely you have some kind of syntax error.

```js
let Url = "https://ipinfo.io/json";
async function getInfo(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
}

(async function main() {
 let ipInfo = await getInfo(Url);
 console.log(ipInfo);
})(); // make auto-running
```

```js
let Url = "https://ipinfo.io/json";
async function getInfo(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return await response.json();
}

getInfo(Url)
  .then(ipInfo => console.log(ipInfo));
```

Comment: Well it's strange. Cause I'm doing the

    let ipInfo = getInfo(Url);
    console.log(ipInfo);

And the console.log is `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`. So it's running even though it's supposed to wait

Comment: Also it is returning a promise. And if console.logged inside of function I'm getting an object (Which is what I want). Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you do `let ipInfo = await getInfo(Url)`. If you don't have the `await`, it'll return the Promise instead. (To do await, you'll have to wrap it in a function like I did in my first example). Using either of the approaches in my examples will change the promise to the value.

Comment: `await is only valid in async functions and async generators`

Comment: Yeah, you have to wrap it in a function like I did with my first example. It's a self-executing async function. Check it out really closely.

Comment: I'm lost. Like this? 

    `getInfo(Url)
      .then(info => {
        initMap();
        // more code
      });`

Comment: Ok, I see it now.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at async structure, it seems like it'd make sense to just put it all in the same function:

```
let Url = "https://ipinfo.io/json";

//Google maps
async function initMap(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  // console.log(response);
  const data = await response.json();
  var place = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: place
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place,
    map: map
  });

  return map;
}

initMap(Url).then(map => { /* Do the rest of your stuff */ })
```

As for why it's firing early, I'd make sure both of the things you're awaiting are in fact returning either promises or async functions.